# I want make a list and and show in double list

Tags: php, mysql, html

I want to make a list fetching data from Database. And I want to show the list double, means half data in one column and half second column. I'm using PHP MySQL and HTML.

Comment: wut?  I think my brain must be dead from the heat today because that made no sense to me.

Comment: that's nice! I'm proud of you! serious: what's your problem? :-) I've no question found in your post...

Comment: SO is not an automatic code generator !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the records, and then calculate how many rows are required per column:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `foo` = 'bar'");
$num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
$num_columns = 2;
$rows_per_col = ceil($num_records / $num_columns);
$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $records[] = $row;
}

// Now get the columns in two arrays:
$col1 = array_slice($records, 0, ($rows_per_col - 1));
$col2 = array_slice($records, $rows_per_col);

// Now loop over the data:
echo '<div class="col">';
foreach($col1 as $row) 
{
    echo "\n\t", '<span class="row">', $row, '</span>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="col">';
foreach($col2 as $row) 
{
    echo "\n\t", '<span class="row">', $row, '</span>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Then you need to add some CSS to float the columns left, and set their width:

```
div.col {
    float: left;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 46%;
}
    div.col span.row {
        display: block;
        line-height: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful your code is useful....

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea without writing it all for you. Loop through your results and when you hit halfway end the current list and start a new one.

You'd probably need to round the halfway point but you should be able to use this to do what you want. Use CSS to position the lists how ever you want. Next time post some code 1st though.

```
$query = YOUR_QUERY
$count = 0; // Set a counter
$total = mysql_num_rows($query); // Get the total

echo '<ul>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { // Loop through the query
    echo '<li>'.$row['something'].'</li>'; // Output your li

    if ($count == ($total / 2) { // If you reach half way, start a new list
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: +1 for the way you broke it :) I was thinking of using `"limit 0,".$count/2` and `"limit ".$count/2.",".$count` . Yours is much cooler though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $returned_data is an associative array,

```
   echo '<table>';
    foreach($returned_data as $k => $v)
    {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo    '<td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$v.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: He just needs data in different columns which means just echo the result in different `<td>` I guess

Comment: Ah I get him now although I don't think he even wants key value, i think he literally just wants two columns with the data in, i.e. first half of the data is in one column, second half of the data is in the second column.  I may still be wrong though lol.

Comment: @JonTaylor No I second your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `css` for this:

```
.list-half {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left; /* to pretend whitespace breaks */
    width: 50%;
}
```

And the output:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $data as $value ) { ?>
    <li class="list-half"><?php echo $value ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Dont forget to clear the `floats`.